# Font not showing in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this issue where upon passing
`ggplot(data.frame(label = "corr:", corr = 1)) +  geom_text(aes(x = factor(1), y = factor(1), label = paste(label, corr), color = label), family = "mono") + guides(color = FALSE) + theme_void()`
I am unable to view the plot the font is not showing up as in:
[image]

I stumbled upon this due to a response in 
this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312493/ggallyggpairs-plot-does-not-display-correlation-coefficients)

*R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)* on *x86_64-pc-linux-gnu*

*ggplot2 version 3.3.1*

Answer (score 0):

changing to `family="sans"` fixed this issue for me (on Ubuntu 20.04, R v 4.0.2):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(label = "corr:", corr = 1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = factor(1), y = factor(1), label = paste(label, corr), 
            color = label), family = "sans") + 
  guides(color = FALSE) + theme_void()
```

see also my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034139/5020785)